# Return subclass when return type is TypeVar

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have the following file `t.py`:

```py
from typing import overload, TypeVar, List, Any, Iterable

class Animal: ...
class Dog(Animal): ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)

def foo(self: T) -> T:
    return self
```

, which type checks fine:

```
$ mypy t.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
(venv) marco@marco-Predator-PH315-52:~/tmp$
```

However, if I change it to:

```
from typing import overload, TypeVar, List, Any, Iterable

class Animal: ...
class Dog(Animal): ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Animal)

def foo(self: T) -> T:
    if isinstance(self, Dog):
        return self
    else:
        return self
```

then I get a typing error:

```
$ mypy t.py 
t.py:10: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Dog", expected "T")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Why is that, and how can I make it type check fine if I have an `if isinstance(self, Dog)` block?

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8354

Comment: Thanks @MarioIshac - my solution for now is to do `    if isinstance(self, Dog): return cast(T, self)
`